# Does the hidden state in an LSTM/GRU change during prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say I create such a model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, GRU

model = Sequential()

model.add( Input( shape=(1,3), batch_size=2 ) )
model.add( GRU(1, stateful=True) )
model.add( Dense(1) )

model.compile( loss="mse", optimizer="adam" )
```

If I call model.predict() with some batch of inputs, will those inputs alter the hidden state (recurrent_kernel_weights)?

If not, then how come? I assumed the hidden state changes with each input in order for the RNN neuron to remember it at a later time.

I called predict with the below inputs and the hidden state did not change.

```
import numpy as np 

inp2 = np.ones(3)
inp3 = np.reshape(inp2, (1,3))
inp4 = []
inp4.append(inp3)
inp4.append(inp3)

inp4 = np.reshape(inp4, (2,1,3))

model.predict(inp5)
```

Comment: You have a big misconception, the hidden state are not the model or kernel weights.

Comment: Currently learning about LSTM. Are they the recurrent_kernel_weights?

Comment: No, the hidden state is not any weight in the layer, it is computed from the input, weights, and previous hidden state.

Comment: So when stateful=True, how are they stored? Cause they need to be utilized when taking in the next input.

Comment: Its just stored in a variable called states inside the layer instance

Comment: Are those variables over-written when you use set_weights to change the models weights? Or do they persistent after set_weights?